# what *should* you get when you add minus-zero to plus-zero?

Tags: floating-point

[this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) did not address this contingency and i am having trouble finding a definitive IEEE-754 document that addresses this.

Comment: it's not off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implication of the line

```
x - x = x + (-x) = +0,   ! (for any finite x, −0 when rounding toward negative)
```

would seem to be that you should get +0.

Comment: "or -0 when rounding toward negative." I would take that literally.

Comment: the funny  thing is, even rounding down, that would imply a non-negative number getting rounded down to a negative number.  that seems very weird.

Comment: i wonder what the rationale is for this -0 resulting if the rounding mode is set to always rounding down.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Usually, it won't be a problem.  By far, the most common system that has both +0 and -0 is 1's complement.  1's complement has the interesting characteristic that it always truncates toward zero: it might truncate to +0 or -0, but it always truncates toward zero.  2's complement, on the other hand, always truncates toward -INFINITY, and this can cause problems in certain signal processing algorithms.  (You do not want to know how I learned this.)